# Flutter DraggableScrollableSheet not showing up on press of a button

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

I want to use `DraggableScrollableSheet` widget on my application, when I use that like with below code, that can show without problem:

```
class HomePage extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: const Text('DraggableScrollableSheet'),
      ),
      body: SizedBox.expand(
        child: DraggableScrollableSheet(
          builder: (BuildContext context, ScrollController scrollController) {
            return Container(
              color: Colors.blue[100],
              child: ListView.builder(
                controller: scrollController,
                itemCount: 25,
                itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                  return ListTile(title: Text('Item $index'));
                },
              ),
            );
          },
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

but when i want to show that by pressing for example `floatingActionButton` that don't show

```
floatingActionButton: GestureDetector(
  child: FloatingActionButton(
    child: Icon(
      Icons.add,
      size: 35.0,
    ),
    elevation: 5,
    backgroundColor: Colors.deepOrange,
    foregroundColor: Colors.white,
    onPressed: (){
      SizedBox.expand(child: DraggableScrollableSheet(
        builder: (BuildContext context, ScrollController scrollController) {
          return Container(
            color: Colors.blue[100],
            child: ListView.builder(
              controller: scrollController,
              itemCount: 25,
              itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                return ListTile(title: Text('Item $index'));
              },
            ),
          );
        },
      ));
    },
  ),
),
```

Comment: Try this https://stackoverflow.com/a/60917972/6618622

Comment: try to use a controller for your draggable , it really help you to change state and position of widget.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

[image]

If you want to do it with `Animation`, here is the solution.

```
class HomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _HomePageState createState() => _HomePageState();
}

class _HomePageState extends State<HomePage> with SingleTickerProviderStateMixin {
  AnimationController _controller;
  Duration _duration = Duration(milliseconds: 500);
  Tween<Offset> _tween = Tween(begin: Offset(0, 1), end: Offset(0, 0));

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _controller = AnimationController(vsync: this, duration: _duration);
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      floatingActionButton: GestureDetector(
        child: FloatingActionButton(
          child: AnimatedIcon(icon: AnimatedIcons.menu_close, progress: _controller),
          elevation: 5,
          backgroundColor: Colors.deepOrange,
          foregroundColor: Colors.white,
          onPressed: () async {
            if (_controller.isDismissed)
              _controller.forward();
             else if (_controller.isCompleted)
              _controller.reverse();
          },
        ),
      ),
      body: SizedBox.expand(
        child: Stack(
          children: <Widget>[
            FlutterLogo(size: 500),
            SizedBox.expand(
              child: SlideTransition(
                position: _tween.animate(_controller),
                child: DraggableScrollableSheet(
                  builder: (BuildContext context, ScrollController scrollController) {
                    return Container(
                      color: Colors.blue[800],
                      child: ListView.builder(
                        controller: scrollController,
                        itemCount: 25,
                        itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                          return ListTile(title: Text('Item $index'));
                        },
                      ),
                    );
                  },
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: thanks a lot, how can dismiss that by scrolling down when that have small size or that is on bottom of screen? like with standard `BottomSheet`

Comment: You should dispose `AnimationController` during widget dispose() method

Answer (score 47):

[image]

---

If you want to use `DraggableScrollableSheet` inside `showModalBottomSheet`, you can simply call this function.

```
void _showSheet() {
  showModalBottomSheet(
    context: context,
    isScrollControlled: true, // set this to true
    builder: (_) {
      return DraggableScrollableSheet(
        expand: false,
        builder: (_, controller) {
          return Container(
            color: Colors.blue[500],
            child: ListView.builder(
              controller: controller, // set this too
              itemBuilder: (_, i) => ListTile(title: Text('Item $i')),
            ),
          );
        },
      );
    },
  );
}
```

Comment: Thanks, man! All of your answers helped me a lot. +1 for you.

Comment: THANK YOU VERY MATCH!!!! You safe my life and my time!!!

Comment: Thank u, it worked for me. Here is an addition from the doc: "the `isScrollControlled` parameter specifies whether this is a route for a bottom sheet that will utilize `DraggableScrollableSheet`. If you wish to have a bottom sheet that has a __scrollable__ child such as a `ListView` or a `GridView` and have the bottom sheet be __draggable__, you should set this parameter to `true`.

Answer (score 12):

If you want to show `DraggableScrollableSheet` as modal you can use material `showModalBottomSheet` method to wrap it. Your sheet will be shown as modal, and you do not have to include it in the widget tree. Please note that under the hood it's pushed as new Route to Navigator, with all its consequences.

```
onPressed: (){
   showModalBottomSheet(
        context: context,
        isScrollControlled: true,
        expand: false,
        backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
        builder: (context) =>
            DraggableScrollableSheet(
              initialChildSize: 0.64,
              minChildSize: 0.2,
              maxChildSize: 1,
              builder: (context, scrollController) {
                return Container(
                  color: Colors.white,
                  child: ListView.builder(
                    controller: scrollController,
                    itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                        return ListTile(
                          title: Text('Item $index'),
                        );
                      },
                    itemCount: 20,
                  ),
                );
              },
            ),
      );
}
```

Comment: By default, `isDismissible` is `true` so u can omit the assignment