# Listview inside DraggableScrollableSheet not scrolling in flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I am designed very heavy nested design like below, the issue when my list expands the listview doesn't seems to be scrolling what is the reason for this, the bottomsheet gets expanded but there is no focus on listview inside it, if i scrolls by touching the 'Operational Hours' text it starts scrolling but when it goes upwards i can't slide it down.

```
_showDialog(BuildContext context) {
    print("_showDialog");
    showModalBottomSheet(
      context: context,
      isScrollControlled: true,
      builder: (BuildContext context) {
        return DraggableScrollableSheet(
          expand: false,
          builder: (context, scrollController) {
            return Container(
              child: Stack(
                children: <Widget>[
                  Column(
                    crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                    children: <Widget>[
                      Align(
                          alignment: Alignment.topCenter,
                          child: Container(
                              margin: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 8),
                              height: 8.0,
                              width: 70.0,
                              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                  color: Colors.grey[400],
                                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10.0)))),
                      SizedBox(height: 16),
                      Padding(
                        padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 24),
                        child: Text('Operational Hours',
                            style: TextStyle(
                                fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                                fontSize: widget.isTab(context)
                                    ? TabTextStyles.mediumText
                                        .copyWith()
                                        .fontSize
                                    : PhoneTextStyles.mediumText
                                        .copyWith()
                                        .fontSize)),
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                  ListView(
                    controller: scrollController,
                    children: <Widget>[
                      SizedBox(height: 54.0),
                      Padding(
                        padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 24),
                        child: Column(
                            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                            children: <Widget>[
                              SizedBox(height: 20.0),
                              Text('Select days to add hours',
                                  style: widget.isTab(context)
                                      ? TabTextStyles.mediumText.copyWith()
                                      : PhoneTextStyles.mediumText.copyWith()),
                            ]),
                      ),
                      DaysList()
                    ],
                  ),
                ],
              ),
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                shape: BoxShape.rectangle,
                color: Theme.of(context).backgroundColor,
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
                  topLeft: Radius.circular(24.0),
                  topRight: Radius.circular(24.0),
                ),
              ),
            );
          },
        );
      },
    );
  }
```

Comment: i think problem with DaysList widget. inside Dayslist which widget you are using column?

Answer (score 40, accepted):

There are couple of mistakes you're making. First, put widgets in `Column` that are always going to be visible at top, second wrap your `DaysList` in `Expanded` and pass `ScrollController` to it.

This is your method:

```
void _showDialog(BuildContext context) {
  showModalBottomSheet(
    context: context,
    isScrollControlled: true,
    builder: (BuildContext context) {
      return DraggableScrollableSheet(
        expand: false,
        builder: (context, scrollController) {
          return Column(
            children: <Widget>[
              // Put all heading in column.
              column,
              // Wrap your DaysList in Expanded and provide scrollController to it
              Expanded(child: DaysList(controller: scrollController)),
            ],
          );
        },
      );
    },
  );
}
```

This is your `Column`:

```
Widget get column {
  return Column(
    crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
    children: <Widget>[
      Align(
        alignment: Alignment.topCenter,
        child: Container(
          margin: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 8),
          height: 8.0,
          width: 70.0,
          decoration: BoxDecoration(color: Colors.grey[400], borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10.0)),
        ),
      ),
      SizedBox(height: 16),
      Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 24),
        child: Text('Operational Hours', style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),),
      ),
      Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 24),
        child: Column(
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
          children: <Widget>[
            SizedBox(height: 20.0),
            Text('Select days to add hours'),
          ],
        ),
      ),
      SizedBox(height: 16),
    ],
  );
}
```

And this is how your `DaysList` should look like:

```
class DaysList extends StatelessWidget {
  final ScrollController controller;

  const DaysList({Key key, this.controller}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ListView.builder(
      controller: controller, // assign controller here
      itemCount: 20,
      itemBuilder: (_, index) => ListTile(title: Text("Item $index")),
    );
  }
}
```

**Output:**

[image]

Comment: I also want to add button at end of bottomsheet which would be fixed at bottom regardless of scrolling..how can i do that ?

Comment: @hiashutoshsingh Do you want to put it as last element in List, may I request a screenshot of what you're trying to achieve?

Comment: @CopsOnRoad What if we want to add draggable behavior to the Header texts like "Operational hours" and "Select days to add hours". But upon reaching top, the header should be fixed.

Comment: @SasankSunkavalli Yes, that can be possible, I'll be updating it when I get some time later today.

Comment: @CopsOnRoad did you have a chance to update your answer to add draggable behavior to the header?

Answer (score 6):

**Screenshot:**

[image]

---

Call this method:

```dart
void showMyBottomSheet(BuildContext context) {
  showModalBottomSheet(
    context: context,
    isScrollControlled: true,
    builder: (_) {
      return DraggableScrollableSheet(
        maxChildSize: 0.8,
        expand: false,
        builder: (_, controller) {
          return Column(
            children: [
              Container(
                width: 100,
                height: 8,
                margin: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 10),
                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20),
                  color: Colors.grey,
                ),
              ),
              Expanded(
                child: ListView.builder(
                  controller: controller,
                  itemCount: 100,
                  itemBuilder: (_, i) => ListTile(title: Text('Item $i')),
                ),
              ),
            ],
          );
        },
      );
    },
  );
}
```