# Vertically Dismissable Screen Implementation on Flutter

Tags: android, flutter, dart, mobile-development, flutter-widget

What I want is simply a vertically dismissible widget. Android equivalent of what I want is [Slidr](https://github.com/r0adkll/Slidr)
and I've been searching for its equivalent in Flutter but I haven't managed to find it.

This if what I want to do;

[image: video.gif]

Any idea on how I can achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With @Mihir Thanekar 's answer, I googled for a bit and finally found an answer which solves my problem.

Answers to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57233622/flutter-draggablescrollablesheet-doesnt-show-up-by-pressing-button) question gives you the answer of how you should show your `DraggableScrollableSheet` and then [this](https://github.com/jamesblasco/modal_bottom_sheet) package enables `dismiss` functionality when the `sheet`'s size is `1.0` which is the entire screen. Native `showModalBottomSheet` method unfortunately is worthless at this point since there is no empty space you can use to swipe down the `sheet`.

Answer (score 1):

I think this can be done with the `DraggableScrollableSheet` widget!

Just set the `initialChildSize` to 0.0 to make it hide to begin.

Then wrap this sheet widget and your TV series list view in a stack, with the sheet above the list.

When you tap a given TV series, you can change `initialChildSize` to 1.0, and rebuild with `setState(()=>{});`

Now you have a draggable sheet that shows up on tap! In order to make the navigation animation, you could use an `AnimationController`, or maybe there's a way to do this without a Stack in which case you could just use `Navigator.pushNamed`.

Thank you, and let me know if you have any further questions.
For more information, check out: https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/DraggableScrollableSheet-class.html

Comment: Updating `initialChildSize` doesn't do anything [as you can see here](https://dartpad.dev/671a54d06b2b2a668100d6a0ed02ad7a)

Comment: Thank you for giving me a guide, even though your exact answer didn't solve the problem, `DraggableScrollableSheet ` was the right answer for me :) Added an answer myself, for people who might run into this need in the future. Thanks again :)